# Is there a quick-nap device for kids too big for a Bjorn (or other) bouncer?

Tags: sleep

Our 13-month-old regularly takes a short nap in the early evening.   It's usually both too short (under an hour) and too close to bedtime (within 2-3 hours) for us to want to put him in his crib in his bedroom.

So, we use the [bjorn bouncer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001HOIC8K) to help lull him to sleep and give him a comfy place to nap that's not confused with "going to bed".

But he's about to outgrow it.   Is there some other device or technique that allows for shorter, more informal naps for a kid too big for a bouncer?

Answer (score 1):

Hammock.  Seriously.  Lots of cultures use them for babies.  You can make one in about 5 minutes by tying two pieces of rope around the ends of a blanket/towel/whatever. -<==>- ascii hammock.

Answer (score 0):

Our three all liked a 'Coorie corner' - basically we'd make a nest of blankets next to wherever we were sitting and just tuck them into it. They'd be next to us and hearing us talking so it wouldn't be a full-on sleep, but they'd get a wee nap.